# Android Studio, Kotlin: BitmapFactory.decodeStream() returns null

Tags: android, image, kotlin, null, decode

I am getting a string from my database that represents a image. I want to transform it into an image again so first I made it a Byte Array and then tried to decode it. What happens is that for some reason it returns null which shouldn't be the case. I printed the size of the array to see if maybe there was an error in the transformation but there wasn't any problem there.

```
private fun imageBit(image: String): Bitmap{
    val b = image.toByteArray()
    d("DEBUG2", "${b.size}") //prints 47109
    val ins = ByteArrayInputStream(b)
    d("DEBUG3", "${ByteArrayInputStream(b).readBytes().size}") //prints 47109
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ins)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out :

```
private fun imgBit(image: String): Bitmap{
val imgBytes = Base64.decode(image, 0)
return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgBytes, 0, imgBytes.size) 
}
```